# Looking for duplicate numbers in an array in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have this code and I want WriteLine duplicit members in array. Can you help me fix it?

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, };
    int n = array.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j<n; j++) 
                    {
                        if (array[i] == array[j]) 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(array[j]); ;
                        }
                    }             
                }
```

Comment: just change `int j = 1` to `int j = i + 1`

Comment: Why don't you just use linq? It is faster, compact and easier..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 1 liner linq statement for you.

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 }.GroupBy(x => x).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} time(s)", x.First(), x.Count()));
```